# Word/Line count tool in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any tool or plugin can do this? CodeBlock has this neat tool which is really nice. Wonder if it's available on Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: You can count by `Notepad++` .. just copy the file into `Notepad++` sheet the `CTL+F` and type your word then click `count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://metrics.sourceforge.net can do lines. I'm not sure about words however.

Answer (score 2):

For newlines, use file search, and search for \n (with regular expressions enabled) in all of the files you want.

For words, you can just make your search term for \w+

The count is the number of matches! If you want anything fancier, make a fancier regex.

Source: http://www.binaryfrost.com/index.php?/archives/207-Easy-way-to-count-Lines-of-Code-in-Eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

Linenumber is always displayed on the lower right corner, and left if you use the context menu an left side of your edit window and check "Show Line Numbers".

Google>: "eclipse word count" shows that many people had the same problem and developed plugins.