# Lines of Code count for Flex in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, code-metrics, line-count

How to get the SLOC count for the Flex code in Eclipse?
Is there a plug-in similar to "Metrics" for finding information about the Flex porject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest way to count lines of code of any particular language and does not require a plugin.

Steps:

1. Click on the root folder of your project
2. Right-click and select Search (or Cntl+H)
3. In the box "Containing Text" type \n and make sure to select the "Regular Expression" checkbox
4. In the "File name patterns" input, type the file extensions of the files you want to include in your count, or click on "Choose" if you are feeling lazy.
5. Click "Search"

BAM! Instant line count for your entire project!

These instructions may differ slightly depending on your version of Eclipse, but you should be able to figure it out.

Good luck!

Comment: Damn nice!!! Unfortunately m done with the flex project a long time back so cant verify anymore...But i think this a pretty good idea and would have worked!

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702136/word-line-count-tool-in-eclipse):

> http://metrics.sourceforge.net can do lines. I'm not sure about words
>   however.

Comment: i am using this already but its not giving me the count for the Flex project. Is there some way to configure it to read the Flex code as well?

Comment: @Andy Sorry, I've never used that plug-in personally before. I just happened to see that other question and thought it might help out. :)